# What type of chart?

Tags: php, jquery, css, charts

We have design of dashboard in one of our project which contains chart like attached image.

We have tried to find this type of chart in jquery and php, but we didn't get that.

Can any one please let me know which type of chart is this?

This is the image of dashboard chart.
[image]

Comment: Make inspect element of your chart. May you can see the chart library name. Or check view source, most of the libraries show have the js as library name.

Comment: Circle area chart